# React-test-utils security

Tags: security, reactjs, testing

**Problem**

We use react-test-utils npm in our React project to run automated tests. And it is necessary for us to test EXACTLY the same code as we put in production so we can't rebuild project without test utils afterwards.

**Question**

Does react-test-utils has any security issues/concerns or is it ok to put it in prodution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here.  Normally, you'd include `react-addons-test-utils` in your devDependencies, and when installing on a production system, you'd exclude these by running `npm i --production`.  I can't think of a single good reason why you'd need to include React's test utils in your production code.  Could you clarify here?

Comment: The way we include test utils is `if(SomeEnvVariable === "tests") window.TestUtils = import("react-test-utils)` so when `SomeEnvVariable` is equal to `tests` then on build we bundle everything together in one js file, including react-test-utils. And based on company policies we have to run our tests on exactly the same build. So if there is no test utils in production build then we cannot run tests on it

Comment: Sounds like a backwards way of doing it if you ask me.  I don't think there are any security issues with React's test utilities, but you need to be aware that the test utils were not meant to be included in production code, since there really isn't a good reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks for comments I will try to reach compromise where we don't use it in production.